# React Native Pan Responder to Animate single dynamic view

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm creating a series of cubes within a grid and I want to only move the cube that is pressed upon. Currently in my code it is moving all the cubes as one. I tried finding the individual key of the cube to try and target it for animation, but I'm not having any luck so far in figuring this out.

The myPanel component is just to layout the cubes that are defined in the renderCube function. It may be an issue with laying out all of the cubes with Animated.View, even though I added the key, but I can't access or figure out how to specifically animate only the selected cube.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, View, ImageBackground, Dimensions, Animated, PanResponder } from 'react-native';
import myPanel from './myPanel';

const DATA = [
{ id: 1, color: '#ff8080' },
{ id: 2, color: '#80ff80' },
{ id: 3, color: '#ffff80' }
];

const winWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const widthCalc = winWidth/400;
const cubeWidth = widthCalc*74;
const winHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const heightCalc = ((winHeight-winWidth)/2)-5;
const xPush = 5*widthCalc;
const borRadius = 7.4*widthCalc;
let cnt = 0;
let xMove = 0;
let yMove = 0;
let currTarget = '033';

class Board extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          pan: new Animated.ValueXY()
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder:(e, gestureState) => true,
            onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
              console.log(this.currTarget);
            },
            onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
                null,
                {
                  dx: this.state.pan.x,
                  dy: this.state.pan.y,
                },
            ]),
            onPanResponderRelease: () => {
                Animated.spring(
                  this.state.pan,
                  {toValue: {x: 0, y: 0}},
                ).start();
            }
        });
    }

    renderCube(item) {
        return (
            <Animated.View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers} 
            style={this.state.pan.getLayout()} key={item.id}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
                onPressIn={()=>{this.currTarget = item.id; console.log('Set '+item.id);}}>
                    <View
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor:myColor,
                            width:cubeWidth,
                                        height:cubeWidth,
                                        position: 'absolute',
                                        top: yMove,
                                        left: xMove,
                                        bottom: 0,
                                        right: 0,
                                        borderRadius:borRadius
                        }}
                    ></View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </Animated.View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <myPanel 
                        data={DATA}
                        renderCube={this.renderCube.bind(this)}
                    />
        );
    }
}

export default Board;
```